# How to normalize channel values to the range[0.0,1.0]?

Tags: android, image, firebase, tensorflow, colors

I'm new to Tensorflow and image processing, I use a code that converts bitmap to an Inputarray for predict object from Tensorflow Lite library and Firebase MLKit custom model API.
I'm trying to normalize channels values to the range[0.0,1.0].
Comments are written show that this function normalizes channels values to a range of [-1.0,1.0] and can be normalized to [0.0,1.0] but doesn't explain how to do that.
How can I do that?

**Update**

The reason for that question is to get correct values from tflite model on an image from ibug dataset:
I have a Tensorflow Lite model and I want to predict eye region landmarks values, I tried to predict eye region points with an image as input and with an array of values ( x and y coordinates )  as output.

I got a python script that gets predictions from an image using Tensorflow lite model.

```
imgUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/Micp1bv.jpg" # image from ibug dataset 
img = Image.open(requests.get(imgUrl, stream=True).raw)
img.load()
img = img.resize((112, 112), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS) # resize to width and height of input tensor parameters

# Normalize to [0, 1]
data = np.asarray( img, dtype="float32" ) /255.0  

# Inference on input data normalized to [0, 1]
inputImg = np.expand_dims(data,0).astype(np.float32)
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], inputImg)

interpreter.invoke()

output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data) // an arrays contains values ( x and y coordinates of landmarks) as an output
```

```java
 private float[][][][] bitmapToInputArray() {
        // [START mlkit_bitmap_input]
        Bitmap bitmap= getYourInputImage();
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 112, 112, true);

        int batchNum = 0;
        float[][][][] input = new float[1][112][112][3];
        for (int x = 0; x < 112; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 112; y++) {
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                // Normalize channel values to [-1.0, 1.0]. This requirement varies by
                // model. For example, some models might require values to be normalized
                // to the range [0.0, 1.0] instead.
                input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
                input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
                input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
                Log.i("Input","input"+input[batchNum][x][y][0]);
                Log.i("input","input"+input[batchNum][x][y][1]);

            }
        }
        // [END mlkit_bitmap_input]

        return input;
    }
```

That was the output from python script:

> [[0.21560352 0.37226492 0.23046923 0.3314699  0.26969466 0.31294012
>     0.31079206 0.32817352 0.32920814 0.367611   0.31699485 0.41163784
>     0.27505988 0.42706913 0.23404554 0.4119034  0.15523753 0.3914298
>     0.18589666 0.37025875 0.22555524 0.3547908  0.27040404 0.3469348
>     0.3122904  0.35289326 0.34334075 0.3686381  0.36434904 0.3907298
>     0.34113637 0.40280795 0.3069372  0.40720087 0.26726058 0.4101103
>     0.22570357 0.40932944 0.1866894  0.40394992 0.6993889  0.3493917
>     0.7078744  0.3110081  0.73927087 0.2935116  0.77587724 0.30691338
>     0.79591703 0.3434749  0.787707   0.38200834 0.7559439  0.3995327
>     0.7166693  0.38873363 0.6655569  0.3727552  0.68886995 0.3488456
>     0.720377   0.3310734  0.75820756 0.3226342  0.79140866 0.3270979
>     0.8144976  0.33877644 0.8281598  0.3576495  0.81746304 0.37150782
>     0.7971135  0.37963405 0.7682784  0.3838213  0.73269796 0.38409975
>     0.69557863 0.3825233 ]]

And this is the output from Android Studio ( Java code ):

> 2019-08-17 17:19:18.754 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,22430149
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.756 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,23864979
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.758 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,27703676
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.759 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,31750143
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.760 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,33583546
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.761 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,32406592
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.762 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,28302023
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.763 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,24265678
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.764 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,16428351
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.765 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,19479913
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.766 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,23414856
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.767 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,27845544
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.767 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,31952256
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.774 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,34978011
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.775 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,37012532
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.776 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,34773278
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.777 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,31446189
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.778 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,27557194
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.778 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,23455118
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.780 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,19578205
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.782 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,69702154
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.785 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,70499951
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.786 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,73528731
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.787 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,77087343
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.788 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,79054081
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.790 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,78286630
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.791 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,75219637
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.792 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,71401721
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.793 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,66399622
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.794 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,68674380
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.795 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,71746421
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.797 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,75426823
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.798 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,78634208
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.799 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,80832106
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.801 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,82105815
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.802 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,81131995
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.805 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,79208875
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.807 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,76439416
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.809 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,72983956
>   2019-08-17 17:19:18.810 19647-19647/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,69351745

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pixel values range from `0` to `255` and you want them to be normalized between `0.0f` and `1.0f` you should just divide the pixel values with 255.

So you should have

```
input[batchNum][x][y][0] = Color.red(pixel) / 255.0f;
input[batchNum][x][y][1] = Color.green(pixel) / 255.0f;
input[batchNum][x][y][2] = Color.blue(pixel) / 255.0f;
```

instead of

```
input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
```

This is because if your pixel value is at its maximum it will be `255` so if you divide by `255.0f` the result will be `1.0f`, and if your pixel value is at its minimum so it is equal to `0` if you divide with `255.0f` you will get `0f`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me. I have a python script that gets predictions from TensorFlow Lite model with an image (the same image to test for prediction on Android ) as input and arrays as output. Values of the array (output) by python script are totally different from the java code ( Android Studio ) , see the update of my post

Comment: If you use these calculations I provided, you do not get values between 0.0 and 1.0?

Comment: Values of what? did you mean value of input[batchNum][x][y][0]?

Comment: Your question is how to normalize channel values to [0.0, 1.0] range. Your current provided code in the question is normalizing values to [-1.0, 1.0] range (input[batchNum][x][y][0], input[batchNum][x][y][1], input[batchNum][x][y][2]). So my answer was to change your current calculations to the calculations i provided in the answer. Are the values not in the wanted range, or something else does not work for you?

Comment: I don't know why I got false values when the TensorFlow lite model is the same.

Comment: Try to use `double` instead of `float` in java because float in java is 32bit precision while `double` is 64bit, and in python i think `float` is also 64bit. Maybe the different results stem from there. And also be sure that you are outputting and comparing the same arrays and values.

Comment: I use `float32` not float 64bit, this is code that I use ( from firebase MLKit )      
 `private FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions createInputOutputOptions() throws FirebaseMLException {
        FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions inputOutputOptions =
                new FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
                        .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1, 112, 112, 3})
                        .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1, 80})
                        .build();
        return inputOutputOptions;
    }`